# Am I reinventing the wheel?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

```
public static void Apply<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, T> func)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        source[i] = func.Invoke(source[i]);
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
 List<string> fruits = new List<string> { "ApPel", "BANana", "oRANGE" };
 fruits.Apply((x) => x.ToUpper());
```

Result: APPLE BANANA ORANGE

- **Am I reinventing the wheel, or does this already exist?**
- **Can Apply be written better?**

Comment: result is: APPEL BANANA ORANGE :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're creating an in-place version of `List<T>.ConvertAll`:

```
fruits = fruits.ConvertAll(f => f.ToUpper());
```

`ConvertAll` is faster than `Select(...).ToList()`, because it never needs to resize a list.

**EDIT**: When you call `.Select(...).ToList()`, the `ToList()` call doesn't know how big the original list was.  Therefore, it will create a small array, then repeatedly resize the array as it fills up.
By contrast, `ConvertAll` is part of the original list, and knows how big it is.  It can therefore allocate an array of the correct size immediately, so it never needs to resize the array.

Your method is faster than either of them because you're modifying the list in-place.  (You never create a new list at all)

Comment: but it does change the type. Can you explain what you mean by your last part more please?

Comment: I take it back. That looks good. I was thinking of ConverAll when you convert objects.

Comment: Also to consider is how these methods would function in the case of an error. Especially his Apply, modifying only half the list and then breaking when a null string is reached.

Answer (score 11):

```
fruits = fruits.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758#SelectTransformation) operator does this.

See the [overload signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357126.aspx):

```
Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)
Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>)
```